# Build web3j to connect to blockchain

Tags: web3j, android

Can't connect to the Ethereum blockchain with web3j 4  for Android Kotlin. Worked in the previous version of web3j.

```
fun web3(): Web3j =  Web3jFactory.build(HttpService("http://192.168.38.148:7545"))
```

Unresolved reference: Web3jFactory

if I try:

```
fun web3(): Web3j = Web3j.build(HttpService("http://192.168.38.148:7545"))
```

I get this error message:

```
W/System.err: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
W/System.err: java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: Exception from call site #59 bootstrap method
W/System.err:     at org.web3j.utils.Async.<clinit>(Async.java:19)
at org.web3j.utils.Async.defaultExecutorService(Async.java:49)
at org.web3j.protocol.core.JsonRpc2_0Web3j.<init>(JsonRpc2_0Web3j.java:88)
at org.web3j.protocol.Web3j.build(Web3j.java:21)
```

Any Idea how to solve this?

Comment: I think there was  some unifying change to web3j 4 for Android.  Anyway you can try web3j gitter

Comment: The tag `web3.js` seems out of place.